# Error on assign char_length to variable

Tags: mysql

The following statement works fine:

```
select char_length(nomoi_queue) from proroute where startNomosPro='low';
```

But when i try to assign char_length to a variable:

```
set @var = char_length(nomoi_queue) from proroute where startNomosPro='low';
select @var;
```

i get no results. What is going wrong;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a proper syntax to assign value to a variable. Try like this:

```
set @var = (select char_length(nomoi_queue) from proroute where startNomosPro='low');
```

or try like this:

```
select char_length(nomoi_queue) into @var from proroute where startNomosPro='low';
```

Comment: MySQL said:
#1064 - you have an error in your sql syntax

Comment: @johnnal:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: In phpmyadmin i get : SQL query: Documentation

set @var := select  char_length(nomoi_queue) from proroute where startNomosPro='low';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 -  with no further details

Comment: @johnnal:- I have updated my answer. Can you check now!

Comment: It works!! Thanks Rahul. But can you explain why your first answer was wrong; ( to understand the logic behind..)

Comment: @johnnal:- Its just that you have to put the entire query in the bracket. So that the return value is treated as a variable. Do upvote as well if possible :)